# Inserting/retrieving image using PixMap in C++/QTCreator

Tags: c++, sql, qt, user-interface

I am studying c++, sql and GUI and I need to insert an image from my DB to my GUI, but is giving me this error "QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record". I've used QDebug and my DB is open and I am connected. Does anyone know why is giving me this error??

Here is my code

```
void MainPageMovies::on_GoButton_clicked()
{
    QString MovieName = ui->SearchMovie->text();
    QByteArray array;
    QSqlQuery query, query1;

    if(query.exec("SELECT * from movie where name = '"+MovieName+"' ")){
        int cnt = 0;
        while(query.next()){
            cnt ++;
        }
        if(cnt > 0){

            query1.exec("SELECT image from poster where name = '"+MovieName+"' ");
            array = query1.value(0).toByteArray();
            QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap();
            pixmap.loadFromData(array);
            ui->SearchedMovie->setPixmap(pixmap);
            ui->SearchMovie->clear();
            ui->page_2->show();
        }
        else{
             ui->label->setText("We could not find this one :/");
        }
    }

}
```

SearchedMovie is my label, where i want to "print" my image.

To insert the image in my DB I used

```
create table poster (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100), format VARCHAR(5), image LONGBLOB, PRIMARY_KEY (id));

insert into poster (name, format, image) values ('Avengers', 'png', LOAD_FILE('/home/thaidy/Documents/FEUP/Mestrado/Projeto de Software/Xilften/GUI/Trabalho/avengers.png'));
```

But when i use the select query it returns my a NULL column

MariaDB [xilften]> SELECT * from poster;

| id | name | format | image |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Avengers | png | NULL |

1 row in set (0.001 sec)

So, I dont know if i am inserting wrong, or my qt code is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: I am looking and I think the error is on the load_file function, but i dont know how to correct. I have /home/thaidy/teste.txt but when I execute SELECT LOAD_FILE('/home/thaidy/teste.txt) gives me null, WHY???

Comment: Futhermore, my secure_file_priv is disabled

Comment: Why are you checking the table `movies` but then access the table `poster`? Is this just an error in the example or in your real code?

Comment: Unrelated to the question but: **Please read about SQL-injection and how to avoid it!!!**